# Vue.js + Pinia: How can I solve problems found by ESLint and TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, eslint, pinia

I'm new to Vue.js + Pinia. I would like to know how to solve these messages.

1. 'state:' is defined but never used.

The code below is `@/stores/user.ts`.

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useUserStore = defineStore('user', () => {
  state: () => {
    return {
      name: ''
    }
  }
})
```

[image]

2. Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Store<"user", {}, {}, {}>'

This file is one of the `vue` files.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { RouterLink, RouterView } from 'vue-router'
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld.vue'
import { useUserStore } from '@/stores/user';

const userStore = useUserStore()

</script>

<template>
  <header>
    < img alt="logo" class="logo" src="@/assets/logo.svg" width="125" height="125" />

    <div class="wrapper">
      <HelloWorld :msg="userStore.name" />

      <nav>
        <RouterLink to="/">Home</RouterLink>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

  <RouterView />
</template>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tricky corner of JavaScript syntax - if an arrow function has curly braces, those are interpreted as the function body. In other words:

```
() => {
  state: () => {
    return {
      name: ''
    }
  }
}
```

is similar to

```
function () {
  state: () => {
    return {
      name: ''
    }
  }
}
```

and means "a function whose body consists of a [labeled statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) that declares an anonymous arrow function but never does anything with it."

To return an object literal, add parentheses, to force the syntax to be an expression instead of a function body.

```js
export const useUserStore = defineStore('user', () => ({
  state: () => {
    return {
      name: ''
    }
  }
}))
```